# How can I apply some kind of pattern on a mesh?

Tags: mesh, texturing, node-editor, sculpting

How can I prepare this type of mesh? With these kind of curved strips. How should I proceed?

[image]

The bottle is whole like this:

[image]

I've trying some stuff like this:

[image]

- I created some separate strips to shrinkwrap on the bottle, and join it. After that, I create a label to shrinkwrap all of these two objects. Or maybe use a lattice to fix it on the bottle. But it doesn’t look good. And I know there is a best way (correct one), but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear if the shape itself is made of this repetitive pattern or if it's a round shape with an added line on its surface.

In the second case you can use the method I describe, except keep only the lines and create another object, a subdivided cylinder that will be deformed with the same *Mesh Deform* modifier, so that both the 2 objects, lines and cylinder, have the exact same shape.

In the first case, you could begin with a 16 vertex circle, keep only 7 of its vertices, duplicate, flip:

[image]

Extrude, flip, bevel:

[image]

Array along the X and the Z:

[image]

Use the *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode) to bend along the Z axis:

[image]

Use the *Mesh Deform* modifier to shape it:

[image]

Comment: I think like this should be great, I gonna try.

Comment: Oh cool, I never tried to do something like this, but this is really helpful for any kind of similar modeling.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann, what do you mean by "something like this"? How would have you done that? I'm curious about all alternative solutions  ;)

Comment: I'd be surprised if someone found something much neater than this. :)

Comment: thanks, it's not perfect because if you squeeze the object it will also squeeze the pattern, but in that case use a Curve modifier with an ellipse instead of the Simple Deform

Comment: @moonboots Sorry that was misunderstandable :) I meant that I never tried to create such thing and never needed to, but seeing your solution and thinking that you could use it for a lot of other patterns makes me think I will do something with it one day :)

Comment: oh ok I was just wondering if you had another solution  ;)